# Is it possible to change the font-size of the values within an ion-picker?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I made an ion-picker with which I can configure the font-size on my Ionic-App. So now I would like to change the font-size within the picker so that the user can see how big the font will be, before he has to confirm it. So for example if you scroll down and select 150%, it should re-scale the font-size to 150% just within the ion-picker.

I already know how to read the current value without confirming it and how to change the font in the entire app, so the only thing that's left would be to change the font of the picker-values.

Comment: Yes it is, just inspect it and target the class or share some code let me look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add global.scss

```
    .picker-opt{
       font-size: 12px;  //change size depend your Requirement
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah.
All what you need is to give the item an id;
And you make normal javascriptcode which is var elementsize = getelementbyid('and put there the item id);
Then 
Elementsize.style["font-size"] = thepicker.value;

And that will solve your problem.
Or in otherway it can be binded with variable and ngmodule with this variable .
Regards.